# SSL engine is getting closed when a secure webapp invokes non-secure external APIs using Apache cxf

Tags: tomcat, ssl, cxf

I have a java web-app running on tomcat8 + jDK1.8 environment. And I have enabled SSL for my web-app using self-signed certificate (i tried the cert generated using keytool) - eg: keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore selfsigned.jks

My application works fine with SSL - till I invoke a module in my app that makes an external API call (this is done within the server-side java code). This external API is not secured (http) and we use Apache CXF to talk to this API and get the data. This API call is also working fine initially, I get the data and page is loading correctly for the first time. But this operation is triggering something on my web server and causing its ssl engine to close. Or this external API call is causing the client browser (Chrome) to fail the SSL connection.

So if refresh the page, nothing is loaded and I started seeing several SSL error on the console "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
Once I get into this state I have to restart my tomcat to work again.

Enabled ssl debug and I see the following:
http-nio-8443-exec-10, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, bad_record_mac
http-nio-8443-exec-10, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
http-nio-8443-exec-10, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

Please help me with this.  I assume we do not need to so any ssl configuration for the external API call as it is not https.

Comment: Just to mention that the external API which we are invoking using cxf is a SOAP API.

Comment: Tomcat's TLS configuration and connections have nothing to do with any outgoing connections that your application may try to make. Any errors between the two are coincidental. If your application makes CXF requests to another service, it will not cause Chrome's connection to fail.

Comment: Please post full stack traces that you are seeing in your log files.